# Windows Phone 8 images looking blurred in 8.1 Universal App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a `windows phone 8` (SilverLight) App. I want to port my app to `Universal 8.1 App`. But the images which are downloaded via 8 App are shown disproportionately (bigger or smaller) on different resolutions. Is there any way,  I can use those images and look good on UI.

1. I **don't want the user to download** images again
2. I am trying to scale in Universal App. I am unable to find a relation between 'scaleFactor' of current device and by what percentage should I scale.

Comment: you can look for viewbox control,

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679923/windows-phone-8-1-dimensions-issue/26687142#26687142) first, including the video linked in the comments.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT The images are in Isolated Storage. Had it been in Appx, I could have provided different images for different scales. I want to use the same images.

Comment: Presumably you know the resolution of the images in pixels. You can compute the size of the elements in XAML using `RawPixelsPerViewPixel` . Therefore you can make the `Image` element the correct size to avoid the content getting blurry.

Comment: As of now, Image element is set to Stretch = "None" given the variety in dimensions of images.